# IPersistTimeouts not registered exception when starting NServiceBus

Tags: c#, azure, nservicebus

I have NServiceBus in an Azure web site and Azure service (web job actually). When launching, I hit the following exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' occurred
>   in Autofac.dll
>
> Additional information: The requested service
>   'NServiceBus.Timeout.Core.IPersistTimeouts' has not been registered.
>   To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the
>   service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use
>   the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Startup code:

```
    var busConfiguration = ServiceBusConfig.Configure("MyEndpointName");
    var startableBus = Bus.Create(busConfiguration);

    startableBus.Start();
```

Configuration:

```
public static class ServiceBusConfig
{
    public static BusConfiguration Configure(string endPointName)
    {
        var config = new BusConfiguration();
        var storageconnectionstring = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
        var serviceBusConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBusConnectionString");
        config.AssembliesToScan(AllAssemblies.Matching("NServiceBus").And("MYAPP."));
        config.CustomConfigurationSource(new ApplicationConfigurationSource());
        config.EndpointName(endPointName);
        config.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
        config.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(c => c.ExistingLifetimeScope(ContainerService.Container));
        config.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence, StorageType.Subscriptions>().ConnectionString(storageconnectionstring).TableName("Subscriptions");
        config.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence, StorageType.Sagas>().ConnectionString(storageconnectionstring);
        config.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence, StorageType.Timeouts>().ConnectionString(storageconnectionstring).TimeoutManagerDataTableName("TimeoutManager").TimeoutDataTableName("TimeoutData");
        config.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>().ConnectionString(() => serviceBusConnectionString);
        config.ScaleOut().UseSingleBrokerQueue();
        config.Transactions().Enable();
        config.EnableInstallers();

        ConfigureConventions(config.Conventions());

        return config;
    }

    private static void ConfigureConventions(ConventionsBuilder conventions)
    {
        conventions.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains("Commands"));
        conventions.DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains("Events"));
        conventions.DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains("Messages"));
        conventions.DefiningEncryptedPropertiesAs(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(a => a.GetType().Name == "EncryptedAttribute"));
        conventions.DefiningTimeToBeReceivedAs(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Expires")
            ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            : TimeSpan.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do code configuration, so here's config.CustomConfigurationSource:

```
public class ApplicationConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    public T GetConfiguration<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(RijndaelEncryptionServiceConfig))
        {
            return new RijndaelEncryptionServiceConfig
            {
                Key = "some key is here"
            } as T;
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(AuditConfig))
        {
            return new AuditConfig
            {
                QueueName = "audit",
                OverrideTimeToBeReceived = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
            } as T;
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig))
        {
            return new MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig
            {
                ErrorQueue = "error"
            } as T;
        }

        return ConfigurationManager.GetSection(typeof(T).Name) as T;
    }
}
```

Although I've used NServiceBus a fair bit, actually having to configure it from the ground up hasn't happened very often, so there is probably a "newbie" mistake lurking somewhere.

I tried `config.DisableFeature<TimeoutManager>()` but no joy. That said, if I have to explicitly enable TimeoutManager, I'm not sure how to do that for Azure.

How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks,
R.